# Background property not working when complete in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I found a problem with safari 5.1.7 on my background propperty wich looks like this: `background:url(http://trovetrade.ml/images/Monitor-Mockup.png) 50% 50% / 100% 100% no-repeat no-repeat` not being like read by the browser, it just do nothing, while this works: `background:url(http://trovetrade.ml/images/iPhone-trovetrade.png) no-repeat 50% 50%` but it's read with the differents options separated(the browser divides them).

And safari is not throwing any console errors but there is a mark near the background-image propperty. Is there a reason why this beaves like this? How could I possible fix this problem.

I also tried this jsfidle when looking for anwsers and didn't work either [link](http://jsfiddle.net/G67Ej/29/)

Comment: Which property are you using `background` or `background-image`? Note that `background-size` is not supported by Safari 5.1 within `background` shorthand.

Comment: background size is not supported? then how would i make the image render by it's total size?I'm using background.

Comment: Try adding your `background-size` property/value after the `background` separately.

Comment: it works! thanks, but that was happening because of an error in safari or just was horribly made?(I know now that I was searching for the wrong thing, should have search for the background-size)

Comment: The answer to your question is that Safari 5 is really really old; it dates from back when the `background` shorthand did not include the  `background-size` property. Support for this started only with Safari 7.